# Webpack Require Dynamic Path From Variable

Tags: webpack, vue.js, require

When I write:

```
require('../assets/home/img_1.jpg')
```

it works fine.

**But** if I write:

```
const path = '../assets/home/img_1.jpg'
require(path)
```

it goes wrong

> the error message shows:
>   Error: Cannot find module "."

When I write:

```
const img_name = 'img_1.jpg'
require(`../assets/home/${img_name}`)
```

it works fine

Why?

Comment: Webpack does not work with completely dynamic variables. It works in the second case because it knows that you want ot load something from `../assets/home` directory and creates one bundle for each of the file inside.